# How to run a Docker Compose image pulled from GitHub Packages

Tags: docker, docker-compose, github-package-registry

I have pushed a Docker image on GitHub Packages and now I would like to pull it and use it.
To run the image locally, I used to go to the related folder and run it with the command `docker-compose up`.
However now, by pulling from GitHub Packages, I just get the Docker image without any folder and I don't know how I can run it.

By inspecting the image it has all the files related to the original folder but, when I try to run the `docker-compose up ghcr.io/giuliomat/bdt-project` command, I get an error saying that there is no docker-compose.yml in the directory. If I just use the command `docker run ghcr.io/giuliomat/bdt-project` it runs one of the two services specified in the docker-compose.yml file. How can I run the Docker Compose image correctly? Thanks in advance!

**Update:** I try to explain myself better. In the image there is a Dockerfile (that now I've uploaded in the question) which is used to build the web service. I developed the image locally and I have no problem running it with `docker-compose up`, but now I wanted to see what it has to be done in order to run it when a user pulls it from my GitHub Packages, and this is my problem. The pulled image should have all the elements needed to run but I don't know what command to use in order to tell Docker to run both services specified in the docker-compose.yml file, since when a user pulls from GitHub Packages it only gets the image and no folder where run `docker-compose up`.

Dockerfile:

[image]

docker-compose.yml:

[image]

content of the pulled docker image:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Update:**

Docker image repository does **not** store yml files, therefore either you provide a `README.md` for the user in the image registry (with yml verbosely copy-pasted there) and/or you provide also the link to the version control repository where the rest of the files reside, so the user can clone and use `docker-compose up`.

---

`docker-compose up [options] [--scale SERVICE=NUM...] [SERVICE...]` means "find [service...]`(if specified, otherwise run all) in`docker-compose.yml` in the current working directory and run it.

So if you move out of the folder with `docker-compose.yml` it won't pick the compose file and therefore won't work.

Also for the image using you need to specify `image` property of a service instead of `build` because `build` works with the `Dockerfile` locally and attempts to build an image instead of *pulling* it from GitHub Docker image registry:

```
web:
  image: "ghcr.io/giuliomat/bdt-project:latest"
```

It'd be the same way you have it for `redis` service.

Also make sure you can pull the image locally first (otherwise `docker login` would be necessary prior to compose commands) by:

```
docker pull ghcr.io/giuliomat/bdt-project
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, maybe because I didn't explain myself well, it does not solve my problem. I've updated the question so I think now it's more clear, my problem is not in the pulling process but in running the image, telling Docker to run both services specified in the docker-compose.yml file contained in the image.

Comment: That's unfortunate. I will do as you suggested and push on GitHub just the web service and add the docker-compose.yml on the repository with the instructions. Thanks a lot for time and help. I appreciate it